# Click on the outlook calendar by searching the calendar Image (_ImageSearch)

Tags: autoit

I am using Imagesearch.au3 to search the calendar image on outlook . Below is the code .

Created a new folder --> ImageSearch.au3 , ImageSearchDLL.dll , and the screenshot of the calendar is placed

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>
$x=0
$y=0
start()
while 1
   sleep(1000)
WEnd
Func Start()
    while 1
        $result = _ImageSearch("cal.png",1,$x,$y,0)
        if $result=1 Then
            ConsoleWrite("Sucesfull")
            MouseMove($x,$y,10)
        Else
            ConsoleWrite("Img not found")
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

Problem : Throws an error message 
"C:\Users...\Desktop\AutoIT\New folder\img\ImageSearch.au3" (44) : ==> Subscript used on non-accessible variable.:
if $result[0]="0" then return 0
if $result^ ERROR

Answer (score 0):

The dll will not load while running as a script. I'm not sure why but it seems others have the same problem. I was able to compile the script as a 64 bit application and then the application loaded the DLL. After changing the tolerance, I was able to find the image.

Also, I would rewrite your code. You have two infinite while loops for no reason. I added a sleep to the remain while loop. I would increase the tolerance.

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>

start()
Func Start()
     while 1
     $x=0
     $y=0
     $result = _ImageSearch("cal.png",1,$x,$y,20)
        if $result=1 Then
           MsgBox(0,"Found Image","moving mouse")
           MouseMove($x,$y,10)
        Else
            MsgBox(0,"Img not found","not found")
       EndIf
       sleep(10000)
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

I tested with the 64bit imagesearch located at http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/page-2

Comment: HI ,

From the above mentioned link , if i click URL links: (The page you requested does not exist)

32bit: ImageSearch 32bit.rar

64bit: ImageSearch 64 bit.rar

 https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=39525.

Could you please send me the correct link , where to download.

Comment: Please let me know from where can i download DLL of imagesearch for windows 64 bit